# How to generate "Embed Picture" on laravel, is there any special method?

Tags: php, laravel, embed

I have a website using Laravel and it stores the images. If other people want to use my picture using tag `<iframe src="#"></iframe>` how can it be generated automatically? Do you have any suggestion how to do that?

Example :

[image: example from giphy.com]

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: just searching on google, but not give me result, 
there is only how to use the embed from other website to my web..

Comment: make an iframe on your site with absolute src of the image, then make it available to copy, thats it

Comment: i was thinking like that tho, but maybe have other ways, thanks.